# Javascript not showing

Tags: javascript

I'm working with javascript for a class. I'm not sure why the file is not displaying anything. Any help would be great.

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        const TAXRATE = .065;
        var = subtotal;
        var salesTax;
        var total;

        subtotal = 329.03;

        salesTax = subtotal * TAXRATE; document.writeln("Sales Tax (raw) = $" + salesTax + "<br>");
        salesTax = parseFloat(salesTax).toFixed(2);
        total = subtotal + salesTax;
        total = subtotal + parseFloat(salesTax);
        total = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);

        document.writeln("Subtotal (one statement) = $" + subtotal + "<br>");
        document.writeln("Subtotal (compound assingment operator) = $" + subtotal + "<br>");

        document.writeln("Sales Tax (raw) = $" + salesTax + "<br>");
        document.writeln("Sales Tax (formatted and now a string) = $" + salesTax + "<br>");

        document.writeln("Total Sale (without parseFloat) = $" + total + "<br>");
        document.writeln("Total Sale (with parseFloat)= $" + total + "<br>");
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: change `var = subtotal;` to `var subtotal = 329.03;`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "=" sign from  `var = subtotal;` then it will work.